# Why don't we take $\sin x$ as negative square root of $1-\cos^2x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am confused of using $\sin x$ as as negative square root of $1-\cos^2x$. Can anyone help please?

Comment: We do if $x$ is in an interval where $\sin x$ is negative.

Comment: $-\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}=-\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}=-|\sin(x)|$

Comment: I'm guessing that you were told that it's wrong to take a negative square root *in a particular problem*.  It would be helpful if we knew what that problem was, so we could figure out why taking the negative square root was wrong

Answer (score 2):

Let's keep $x$ in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. If $0\le x< \pi$, then $\sin x\ge0$, so $\sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$. If $\pi\le x< 2\pi$, then $\sin x\le0$, so $\sin x=-\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$:
$$
\sin x=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{1-\cos^2x} & \text{if $0\le x<\pi$} \\[6px]
-\sqrt{1-\cos^2x} & \text{if $\pi\le x<2\pi$}
\end{cases}
$$
For angles outside that interval, first reduce to it by adding or subtracting integer multiples of $2\pi$.

(For $x=0$ or $x=\pi$ it's immaterial what branch you use, because the sine is $0$.)

If you don't know where $x$ is according to the division above (after reduction), what you can say is that
$$
\lvert\sin x\rvert=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}
$$